# Input tag has value but still is empty

Tags: html

I have a peculiar case here wherein the input tag has value in its value attribute but the input box is still empty on the page.

```html
<input class="form-control myInput" id="myInputId" maxlength="10" name="test" type="text" 
    value="2244-0099ABC" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);">
```

But when I try to add the same value which is present in the value attribute using jquery or at console, then the value appears. 
Please let me know where it is that I'm going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: It is working fine here (https://jsfiddle.net/y6674sz9/)

Comment: Thanks, Tym.. But for some reason it isn't working for me.

Comment: Your code is working fine . check the code snippet

Comment: Maybe you have conflict with some script the reset your value or something. We can't know this. Do you have a public URL for your project or can you upload it? **Or you can run the page without javascript and check if the problem still occur**

Comment: Thanks guys, I found a jquery code which is messing with  my code.

Comment: @MichaelPhilips Can you tell me which jquery code was causing this issue? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this..**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <input class="form-control myInput" id="myInputId" maxlength="10" name="test" type="text" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);">
    </body>
</html>             

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    var data="2244-0099ABC";
    jQuery(".myInput").val(data);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Though my issue was related to some jquery which I found out later, I've accepted your answer to close this question. But I appreciate your effort to help, thanks.

Comment: Anytime @michaelPhilips